# Why is my model rendered in Black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I ned suggestion for this material. I have a normal principled node with orange color. In viewport and lookdev mode it is orange but in render view, and when hit render, it shows as black. I have checked that faces are oriented correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a top lid its showing the material as expected in blue. Why is the base showing black?

Comment: It seems that the shape casts shadow on itself.

Comment: @lemon in the lookdev it does not. It show original color

Comment: There is something weird... I can select some edge only parts. I think this is due to that.

Comment: This is due to custom normals (but not only)

Comment: @lemon normal facing out side

Comment: Yes but there is custom normals. I don't know if this is wanted. Make a copy of the mesh, go to object data property, then geometry and clear custom normals.

Comment: @lemon I took a geometry node -> true normal -> normal of principle bsdf and it work. Thanks